# h! nor H working for table floats

Tags: tables, floats

I'm trying to get a table in to a section I want but it wont play ball,
The first table shows above the allowed paragraph and the second table in the allowed paragraph, how can I fix it?

I use the `\usepackage{float}` package.

Thanks

```
\paragraph{Allowed}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Rule & Who & Controlled \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\paragraph{Not allowed}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Rule & Who & Controlled \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This is one of the most asked questions on the site. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017). Perhaps the simplest solution for you is not to use the `table` environment at all and use the `\captionof` facility of the `caption` package.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with making a table in the /paragraph section. As the floats work in other non paragraph section.

Comment: But if you want it there and nowhere else, you don't *want* it to float. Floats... float. It is their essential nature.

Answer (score 5):

In such a case do *not* use a floating object. Use instead

```
\usepackage{caption}
...

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{A table, what else?}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Rule & Who & Controlled \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

...
```

Comment: I'd mention also `\usepackage{caption-of}`, that can be handy for the cases where `\usepackage{caption}` can't be employed (some classes are incompatible with it).