# How to make row spacing in the table environment the same as in the document

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I am writing a document class for my thesis, and now I am trying to control the line spacing in the `table` environment. I use `\setstretch{1.5}` to set the line spacing for main text. I want to make the line spacing in `table` (or `table`-like) environment to be the same (`\baselinestretch`=1.5). However, it seems like `\setstretch` only affects `tabular` or `table` with `[H]` option. In `table` with common floating options, the stretch is reset to 1. The following MWE may of some help:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{scale=0.75}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for MWE
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setstretch{1.5} % set the line spacing

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[H] % Here the line spacing is correct.
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table 1}
    \label{tab:my_label1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht] % Here is not.
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table 2}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I obtain the same line spacing in `table` as in the document texts?
Besides, I notice that if I put an `\setstretch` inside the `table`, the line spacing is correct. But I don't want put this in all of my tables, can it be set globally? (By the way, I tried `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setstretch{1.5}}` with `etoolbox` package, but it does not work.)

```latex
\begin{table}[ht]
    \setstretch{1.5} % After adding this, the line spacing is correct.
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
        test & test \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table 3}
    \label{tab:my_label3}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TexSE. With \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} in the preambule

Comment: Thank you @pascal974 . But this will stretch the `tabular` and `table[H]` by another 1.5, which makes the line spacing become 2.25 in these environments.

Comment: I found this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179444/h-nor-h-working-for-table-floats. Maybe replace \begin{table}[H] with a minipage...

Comment: Put  `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` in the float, not in the preamble, or (better) for the shake of the document layout , set this in the preamble, and do not use fake floats with [H] at all.